# How to change tooltip of an esriControl?

Tags: arcobjects, arcgis-desktop

Is there a way to change an esriControl's tooltip?

I tried using the ICommand interface but the tooltip propertry is read-only.

If I have to build a whole new ICommand and/or ITool is there anyway I can extend an esriControl so I do not have to build a new control from scratch?

Comment: I inadvertently deleted a comment by @blah238 (my apologies), who would like to know what an "esricontrol" might be.

Comment: Hi,

Thank you for your response.  Esricontrols allow you to use the controls in ArcMap/ArcCatalog in your custom application.  Here is a page listing allow of them.   They all implement the ICommand interface.   Thanks again.

http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/ICommand_Interface/00430000001s000000/

David